why Failed to write data to connection ResolvedIPv4Address in neo4j?
I am trying to save data in neo4j. I got the following exception:
Failed to write data to connection ResolvedIPv4Address(('34.69.128.95', 7687)) (ResolvedIPv4Address(('34.69.128.95', 7687)))
This exception will be generated when I add this function (just defining the function and not calling it)
    words = s.split()
    if not words:
        return s
    first_word = words[0].lower()
    capitalized_words = [word.capitalize() for word in words[1:]]
    return "".join([first_word] + capitalized_words)````

Any suggestion please?



Show the entire function, and enough of your code to gives us a clue as to what you are doing and what might be going wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Am also getting the same issue. Any break through ?
Failed to write data to connection ResolvedIPv4Address(('34.126.161.242', 7687)) (ResolvedIPv4Address(('34.126.161.242', 7687)))
Failed to write data to connection IPv4Address(('a2e82f9a.databases.neo4j.io', 7687)) (ResolvedIPv4Address(('34.126.161.242', 7687))

Please answer the question. Responses such as "I am getting the same issue without resolution" are not helpful

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
